# Is this Go code thread safe or do I need a mutex?

Tags: multithreading, go, mutex, race-condition

Suppose I have the following function, `doWork`, that starts some work in a goroutine and returns a `Result` to check for completion and error:

```
func doWork() *Result {
    r := Result{doneCh: make(chan struct{})}
    go func() {
        var err error
        defer func() {
            r.err = err
            close(r.doneCh)
        }()
        // do some work
    }()
    return &r
}
```

where `Result` is the following struct:

```
type Result struct {
    doneCh      chan struct{}
    err         error
}
// doneCh returns a closed chan when the work is done.
func (r *Result) Done() <-chan struct{} {
    return r.doneCh
}
// Err returns a non-nil err if the work failed.
// Don't call Err until Done returns a closed chan.
func (r *Result) Err() error {
    return r.err
}
```

is this code thread safe if I set `err` before closing `doneCh`:

```
defer func() {
    r.err = err
    close(r.doneCh)
}()
```

or is the compiler free to order the `r.err = err` and `close(r.doneCh)` instructions as it likes, in which case I'd need a mutex to prevent concurrent read/writes on error.

Comment: The documentation states “Within a single goroutine, reads and writes must behave as if they executed in the order specified by the program”, so once `doneCh` is closed, `err` must have been written.

Comment: Why creating a `struct` with a channel to signal the end and some value to read instead of using the channel to send the value? Channels are thread-safe by construction, structs aren't, make use of them.

Comment: @Adirio because I'm using it more like a context. There are other functions for Result (it's also not called Result) that are removed from the example above as the extra code isn't relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Could you then edit yoru answer to include a bit more detail (still keeping it simple if you wish) that would retain you from using the answer I gave you? You are probably able to send a more complex type than `error` through the channel to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler may not reorder the assignment and close statement, so you do not need a mutex if callers are well-behaved and do as instructed by your docs.

This is explained in [The Go Memory Model, Channel Communication](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_7).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the link too, looks like an exact mirror of the code above! :-)

Answer (score 4):

It is thread-safe only if your comments are obeyed and `Err()` is never called until a read from `Done()` returns.

You could simply make `Err()` blocking though by re-implementing it as:

```
func (r *Result) Err() error {
    <-r.doneCh
    return r.err
}
```

Which would guarantee that `Err()` only returns after done is complete. Given that err will be nil until the work errors, you have no way of telling if `Err()` is returning successfully because work was finished or because it hasn't completed or errored yet unless you block on `Done()` first, in which case why not just make `Err()` blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `chan error` and testing if the channel is opened or closed on reception?

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func delegate(work func(ch chan error)) {
    ch := make(chan error)

    go work(ch)

    for {
        err, opened := <- ch
        if !opened {
            break
        }
        // Handle errors
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    // Example: error
    delegate(func(ch chan error) {
        defer close(ch)
        // Do some work
        fmt.Println("Something went wrong.")
        ch <- errors.New("Eyyyyy")
    })

    // Example: success
    delegate(func(ch chan error) {
        defer close(ch)
        // Do some work
        fmt.Println("Everything went fine.")
    })

    // Example: error
    delegate(func(ch chan error) {
        defer close(ch)
        // Do some work
        fmt.Println("Something went wrong more than once.")
        ch <- errors.New("Eyyyyy 1")
        ch <- errors.New("Eyyyyy 2")
        ch <- errors.New("Eyyyyy 3")
    })
}
```